# Unable to set property '0' of undefined or null reference in my for loop when setting a new array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've got a bit of code that runs through an array and then adds commas to the numbers that come through. this work if I just do alert(finnumber.toLocaleString()); I get all the correct numbers however once I try and put those numbers into a new array by doing the below code all I get.

Unable to set property '0' of undefined or null reference

```
var Finarray = [];

for (var p = 0; p < SLarray.length; p++) {
var finnumber = ((SLarray[p][1]) / 100);
Finarray[p][0] = finnumber.toLocaleString();
alert(Finarray);
}
```

none of Slarray are undefined references there all numbers besides one that is a 0.

If anyone could help that would be great thanks

Comment: We need to see what SLarray contains in order to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize array before you can use it.

```
Finarray[p] = [finnumber.toLocaleString()];
```

*OR*

```
Finarray[p] = [];
Finarray[p][0] = finnumber.toLocaleString();
```

instead of

```
Finarray[p][0] = finnumber.toLocaleString();
```

Comment: Thank you totally forgot the finarray[p] = [] ;

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
Finarray[p][0] = finnumber.toLocaleString();
```

you're trying to write to index 0 of an array (`Finarray[p]`) that doesn't exist. If you want there to be an array at `Finarray[p]`, you need to create it:

```
Finarray[p] = [];
Finarray[p][0] = finnumber.toLocaleString();
```

...or more concisely:

```
Finarray[p] = [finnumber.toLocaleString()];
```